# Get YouTube channel subscriptions video JSON list

Tags: ios, json, video, youtube-api, subscriptions

I have an iOS application which loads content of YouTube V3 API. I am to authenticate with the Google servers and get the users YouTube channel ID. However, I have one problem: no matter how much I have searched through the Google API documentation, I have not be able to find a way to get a JSON list of videos from the channels that particular user is subscribed to.

So YouTube has this sections where the user can view all the new videos from all the channel he/she is subscribed to. How can I get the JSON file for this?

Does anyone know the YouTube API URL for this?

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities
See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#resource
It's located in the activities resource. There are different types. Filter on type: upload.

Unfortunately, it's always behind compared with YouTube. Meaning while you can see new videos in YouTube you need to wait some time before they appear thru the API.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Worked perfectly.